# JweAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_256, JweEncryption.A256GCM .net Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, rsa

I am trying to decrypt a JWE return by a Mulesoft API with .Net Core 2.0

I get the JWE, the stock in string. The private key and its password are also correct.

When I decode, I have an error System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : 'Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.'

But in the first part of jwe "eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUC0yNTYiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0" in base64 => {"alg":"RSA-OAEP-256","enc":"A256GCM"}

```
//get private key
TextReader decrypterPrivateReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(decrypterPrivateFile);
PemReader decrypterPrivatePemReader = new PemReader(decrypterPrivateReader, new PasswordFinder(decrypterPrivatePwd));
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters decrypterPrivateKey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)decrypterPrivatePemReader.ReadObject()).Private;

RSAParameters decrypterPrivateParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(decrypterPrivateKey);
RSACryptoServiceProvider decrypterPrivateProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
decrypterPrivateProvider.ImportParameters(decrypterPrivateParams);

//decode token
return Jose.JWT.Decode(jwe, decrypterPrivateProvider, JweAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP_256, JweEncryption.A256GCM);
```

Thanks all

Comment: Try `RSACng` instead of `RSACryptoServiceProvider`

Comment: it works. Tanks a lot

Comment: it works for windows but in unix "Windows Cryptography Next Generation (CNG) is not supported on this platform." .

Answer (score 1):

The use of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is what is holding you back, the only OAEP it understands is OAEP-SHA-1.

When on .NET Core the correct RSA is always `RSA.Create()`.  The returned object is always correct for the platform you're running on, and (as of 2.1) can always do SHA-2-based OAEP.

If you're on .NET Framework then RSA.Create() will return an RSACryptoServiceProvider, so you'll need to special case .NET Framework to build an RSACng instead.